# ModuleNotFound: No module named 'SpeechRecognition'

Tags: flask, speech-recognition, python-3.7

I'm using Python 3.7.8

ModuleNotFound: No module named 'SpeechRecognition' appears when I try to run my project.
[ModuleNotFound: No module named 'SpeechRecognition'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcCU9.png)

But it works well when I try it with python -m speech_recognition:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfAPm.png)

Comment: I import speech_recognition as sr, didn't work, as well at import SpeechRecognition

Answer (score 0):

How to start flask app. I recommend to start like this. `main.py` is flask start script file.

```sh
# set flask start script file
export FLASK_APP=main.py

# run flask
python3 -m flask run
```

```py
# main.py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

Comment: I can start it without import speech_recognition line

Comment: change main.py to your flask startup script. and run it again.

Comment: did it,
somewhat my python clashed with my conde , so i just uninstall n reinstall python to start clean, worked